# How do I configure logging in a Web Host mounted with Host.CreateDefaultBuilder

Tags: c#, service, .net-core

I am adapting the following `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` method which works, into one based on `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` So that I can use the `UseWindowsService` [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

```cs
// WORKING
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
      ...
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

When I try to adapt this...

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    { // tried here
      ...
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
      webBuilder.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        { // tried here too
          ...
        });
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

I get the following error...

> Unable to resolve service for type 
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory'  while attempting to
>   activate 'MyProject.Startup'.

What is the appropriate way to setup logging here?

Comment: @Nkosi ... I don't think it should matter as the WebHost.CreateWebHostBuilder version works ... Here it is in a pastebin as I don't want to overload the question.  https://pastebin.com/CSWPkePh

Comment: In the past, I've had configuration options under ConfigureServices or Configure blow up, and no output in the logs/console.  For now, it's working, but troubleshooting is very difficult without being able to log at startup.

Comment: I believe `Configure` still allows for the factory as one of the injectable parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Reference [App startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup)

> Only the following service types can be injected into the `Startup`
> constructor when using the Generic Host (`IHostBuilder`):
>
> - IWebHostEnvironment
> - IHostEnvironment
> - IConfiguration

While your linked `Startup` appears to be injecting outside of the allowed services.

```
public Startup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  this._Factory = loggerFactory;
  this._Logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
}
```

Based on the linked `Startup` code, the logger does not appear to be used and the one reference to the logger is commented out, since based on the context of where it is used, it is not needed.

I would suggest removing the injection of the `ILoggerFactory` from `Startup` constructor as part of the refactoring to the newer version of the framework.

Everything else the original example code provide appears to be following the suggested format from the documentation and should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you... just found a reference for this in GH Issues. *sigh* sad that this functionality is broken... I already removed the logger in startup, and enabled `webBuilder.CaptureStartupErrors(true);`  Should probably recommend that setting in the docs since logging no longer works, not sure if the prior behavior to bury exceptions in ConfigureServices/Configure still happens.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9337